# Frequency mean by group

Tags: r, mean

I want to calculate mean and sd for frequencies by group in **R**. Here is my data:

```
           Opinion 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11
      Group 
      A            0  1  1  0  3 15  8  9 12  5  3
      B            1  3  5  8 15 18 17 14 15  9  4
      C            8  4 15 19 14 25 17 16 20  4  6
      D            0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0
      E            0  6  5  8 12 14 15 15 14  7  8
      F            1  0  0  0  1  1  0  1  1  0  0
      G            3  0  4  4  1  1  1  1  1  0  1
```

What I want to calculate is mean and sd for every group (A,B,C,D,F,G). Every cell is frequency. In particular, it is a number of answers that every "Opinion" received from respondents. For instance, respondents that are supporter of group A, on average answer with opinion 7.5 and sd 1.9.

I calculate by hand mean and sd for every group. How to write a loop that can calculate this at once? I am sure somebody here already knows that. I would really appreciate your help. Thank you.

P.S. `apply()` will not work because I need mean and sd of frequencies.

Comment: `apply(data,1,mean)` and `apply(data,1,sd)`, 1 stands for first dimension traversal, aka rows.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [r get mean of n columns by row](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31683217/r-get-mean-of-n-columns-by-row)

Comment: @dash2 It's not that simple. The position of the values within the rows plays a decisive role here. So `rowMeans` or `apply(data,1,mean)`  won't give the right result.

Comment: @RHertel ah, I get it. I missed the 'every cell is frequency' part. So then the mean of row A is 6.5, not 7.5, no?

Comment: @dash2 The mean of row A, without accounting for the position of the numbers within the row, would be 5.18. But this would just represent the average number of answers that have been given in group A. In particular, that value would not consider the opinion that has been given. The answers below provide the values for the "average opinion" of each group.

Answer (score 1):

For the calculation of the mean of each group you can use the following code:

```
the_means <- setNames(rowSums(col(df1)*df1) / rowSums(df1),
                      LETTERS[seq_len(nrow(df1))])
#> the_means
#       A        B        C        D        E        F        G 
#7.526316 6.761468 6.013514 7.000000 6.846154 5.800000 4.529412
```

**data:**

```
df1 <- structure(list(V1 = c(0L, 1L, 8L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 3L), V2 = c(1L, 3L,
 4L, 0L, 6L, 0L, 0L), V3 = c(1L, 5L, 15L, 0L, 5L, 0L, 4L), V4 = c(0L, 8L,
19L, 0L, 8L, 0L, 4L), V5 = c(3L, 15L, 14L, 0L, 12L, 1L, 1L), V6 = c(15L, 
18L, 25L, 0L, 14L, 1L, 1L),  V7 = c(8L, 17L, 17L, 1L, 15L, 0L, 1L), 
V8 = c(9L, 14L, 16L, 0L, 15L, 1L, 1L), V9 = c(12L, 15L, 20L, 0L, 14L, 1L, 
1L), V10 = c(5L, 9L, 4L, 0L, 7L, 0L, 0L), V11 = c(3L, 4L, 6L, 0L, 8L, 0L, 
1L)), .Names = c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4", "V5", "V6", "V7", "V8", "V9", 
"V10", "V11"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

Comment: Were you planning to answer the second part of the question?

Comment: @Frank I tried but I gave up after some time since I didn't find an elegant solution. If you have one, go ahead...

Comment: Nope, got nothing besides installing a package with functions named like rowMeans and rowSds, or maybe a grossly inefficient option like `lapply(split(m, row(m)), summary)`. Oh, never mind just read your comment above and the actual question and I see it's complicated.

Answer (score 1):

For the means (using @RHertel's lovely, reproducible data)

```
apply(df1, 1, function(x) weighted.mean(1:11, w = x))
# [1] 7.526316 6.761468 6.013514 7.000000 6.846154 5.800000 4.529412
```

For the standard deviations:

```
apply(df1, 1, function(x) sqrt(weighted.mean((1:11)^2, w = x) - weighted.mean(1:11, w = x)^2))
# [1] 1.883495 2.254045 2.552123 0.000000 2.448584 2.785678 2.767833
```

We use the definition `Var(X) = E(X^2) - E(X)^2`, and take the square root of that for the standard deviation. If you want the the sample standard deviation you can multiply by `sqrt(rowSums(df1) / (rowSums(df1) - 1))`. This will, of course, result in `NA` or `NaN` for group D with only 1 observation.

To make this more general, you could replace the `1:11` bits with `as.numeric(colnames(df1))` or whatever is appropriate. It' hard to tell what data structure you have, a `table` perhaps?

Comment: Nice! Maybe a more general way could consist in replacing `1:11` with `seq_len(ncol(df1))`.

Comment: I'm skeptical it's a data.frame at all - my guess is a table object. And then I like the `as.numeric(colnames())` suggestion as it should work even for non-sequential, non-1-starting columns (e.g., `df1 = table(am = mtcars$am, cyl = mtcars$cyl)`). And I'm also happy to leave those tweaks to the end user.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to post my solution too.

What I did is:

1. Created a `data.frame()` from `table()`

   ```
   b1 <- data.frame(table(data$Group, as.numeric(data$Opinion)))
   ```
2. Expanded the data from frequencies to vectors (otherwise R kept showing what I would get if I used `apply()`)

   ```
   b2 <- b[rep(row.names(b), b$Freq), 1:2]
   ```
3. Used a loop from `ddply()`

   ```
   b3 <- ddply(b2, .(Var1), summarize, mean = mean(as.numeric(Var2), na.rm = TRUE), sd = sd(Var2))
   ```